# Construct a Deterministic Finite Automata (DFA) for the language 1*01 (11)*(0 U 1)*,

Tags: dfa

Construct a Deterministic Finite Automata (DFA) for the language where the set of all strings are of the form `1*01 (11)*(0 U 1)*`, that contain 01 as a substring

Comment: So where are you stuck? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Without providing the direct answer, you should know the building blocks to be able to arrive there. Given that you know how finite automata work (otherwise read 'Languages and Machines' by Sudkamp), the DFA has a transitation for every symbol in every state:

> Unlike for non-deterministic finite automata or NFA that we encounter in the next section, for a DFA in each state q ∈ Q and for every symbol a ∈ Σ the next state,
>   which is the state δ(q, a), is determined by the transition function δ. [1](https://www.win.tue.nl/~evink/education/2it70/PDF2016/2it70-chap2.pdf)

Note: if you are a visual thinker and you wonder how the diagrams in these books are constructed, here is [an example visualisation](https://dreampuf.github.io/GraphvizOnline/#digraph%20dfa%20%7B%0D%0A%20rankdir%3DLR%3B%0D%0A%20%20%22%22%20%5Bshape%3Dnone%5D%0D%0A%20%20%22start%22%20%5Bshape%3Dcircle%2C%20style%3Dfilled%2C%20fillcolor%3Dyellow%5D%0D%0A%20%20%22s1%22%20%5Bshape%3Ddoublecircle%5D%0D%0A%20%20%22s2%22%20%5Bshape%3Dcircle%5D%0D%0A%20%20%22s3%22%20%5Bshape%3Dcircle%5D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%22s1%22%20-%3E%20%22s1%22%20%5Blabel%3D%220%2C%201%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20%22s2%22%20-%3E%20%22s2%22%20%5Blabel%3D%221%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20%22%22%20-%3E%20%22start%22%0D%0A%20%20%22s2%22%20-%3E%20%22s3%22%20%5Blabel%3D%220%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20%22s3%22%20-%3E%20%22s1%22%20%5Blabel%3D%220%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20%22s3%22%20-%3E%20%22s4%22%20%5Blabel%3D%221%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20%22start%22%20-%3E%20%22s1%22%20%5Blabel%3D%220%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20%22start%22%20-%3E%20%22s2%22%20%5Blabel%3D%221%22%5D%0D%0A%7D).